# Функция gmtime, ошибка «невозможно преобразовать аргумент из long * в const time_t *»

Tags: c++, c

Я скачал проект с Github, собрал его, но у меня выскакивает две ошибки при компиляции:

1) `tm *gmtime(const time_t *const )": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "long *" в "const time_t *const`

2)`strftime: функция не принимает 3 аргументов`

Обе ошибки связаны с библиотекой time.h

Вот строка, на которой выскакивает ошибка:

```
strftime(buffer, 80, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", gmtime(&curTime.tv_sec));
```

Реализация функций в time.h:

```
_ACRTIMP size_t __cdecl strftime(
    _Out_writes_z_(_SizeInBytes)  char*            _Buffer,
    _In_                          size_t           _SizeInBytes,
    _In_z_ _Printf_format_string_ char const*      _Format,
    _In_                          struct tm const* _Tm
    );
```

и

```
static __inline struct tm* __CRTDECL gmtime(
            _In_ time_t const* const _Time)
        {
            #pragma warning(push)
            #pragma warning(disable: 4996)
            return _gmtime64(_Time);
            #pragma warning(pop)
        }
```

Comment: В первом случае вы передаёте указатель на поле `tv_sec` структуры типа `timeval`. А оно имеет тип `long`. Функция же `gmtime()` принимает указатель не на `long`, а на `time_t`. О чём вам совершенно чётко написано в сообщении. Возможно, вторая ошибка - следствие первой, не знаю как это в вашем компиляторе (gcc, например, съедает такое).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. В C++11 тип `time_t` изменили с целого на вещественный. Могу предположить, что ваш `curTime.tv_sec` имеет тип `long` и его нельзя просто так привести к указателю на вещественный.

   Строчкой выше надо сделать следующее:

   ```
   time_t tv_sec = static_cast<time_t>(curTime.tv_sec);
   strftime(buffer, 80, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", gmtime(&tv_sec));
   ```
2. Скорее всего, следствие из первого.

Comment: Справедливости ради, стоит заметить, что тип `long` также является вещественным типом (real type). С11, 6.2.5/17: "The _integer_ and _real floating types_ are collectively called **real types**". Так что `time_t` запросто может быть псевдонимом `long`. Однако, полагаться на это не стоит.

Answer (score 1):

В Visual С++ (вы, судя по всему, работаете с ним) тип `time_t` - это `long long`, а указатели на `long long` и на просто `long`, как вы понимаете, несовместимы.